# why not using simple jquery events instead of kendo window.observable?

Tags: jquery, mobile, kendo-ui, telerik

i have been going through the mobilegap kendo tutorial of creating a gallery and got to the point where it told me to assign some events via `kendo.observable`

specifically, there is a simple photo list view and the code is supposed to look like this

```
window.listview = kendo.observable({
  addImage: function() {
    ...do stuff...
  }
});
```

then on a button we add this attribute `data-bind="click:addImage"`

ok, this works. but i absolutely do not undestand why is this necessary, since i could simply do

```
$("button").click(function(){
  ...do stuff...
}
```

why is it adviced to fetch events via kendo.observable? and why does it even need to be assigned to window.listview?

what if i have a generic application and not a list view of photos?

i am missing the point here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific example, there really isn't a great reason to use one over the other, except maybe consistency. I can however think of a few good situations where Kendo's bound events excel over jQuery:

1. Bound buttons are often context aware. If your button is bound to a specific item in a collection the data bound function will be passed that item's data when clicked. Something like a delete button added to each item in a listview:

Exmaple:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    // vm stuff...
    DeleteMe: function(e) {
        this.someDataSource.remove(e.data);
    }
}
```

VS

```
// vm stuff...

$('.delete-button').on('click', function(e) {
    var myId = $(this).parent().data('uid'); // Assuming the delete button's parent is the list item...
    var data = viewModel.someDataSource.getByUid(myId);
    viewModel.someDataSource.remove(data);
})
```

2. Dynamically generated items. In the example above, if we added a new item to the collection we would need to once again assign the events to all of the new buttons. When using data bound events in a template however, they are created automatically whenever new items are created.
3. Remote data access and other asynchronous operations. If the listview is bound to a remote DataSource, all of the items with buttons may not be created by the time the jQuery code above runs. You would need to use even more events like DataSource change to wait for all of the data to be loaded before assigning the event listeners. Again, template bound functions handle this automatically.

Of course, in the end it all comes down to preference. If you are more comfortable using jQuery then by all means use it. I tend to go with whatever method amounts to the most concise, readable, and bug free code. MVVM stuff also comes more naturally to me because of my C# background but even then I find myself mixing the two sometimes.

To answer your other questions:

```
window.listview = something;
```

is pretty much the same as

```
var listview = something;
```

If you are in the right scope.

All of the MVVM stuff is more useful in a data driven app instead of just a photo viewer.